# zeitgeist-daemon excessive RAM usage

Tags: 11.04, 64-bit, zeitgeist, ram

I have installed last week Ubuntu 11.04 64 on a new machine. I am running the GUI using Unity. However I have noticed that after 1-2 hours the process zeitgeist-daemon starts using excessively the machine's memory. Up to 800 - 1000 MB!

I am having the same issue on another machine where I used to run Ubuntu 11.04 for several months without problems until using Gnome. The last few days I have changed to Unity and the exact same problem occurs.

I am forced to kill the process otherwise I am unable to keep working with the machines.

Should I file a bug?

Comment: Vote for close as this is a bug and we don't deal with bugs on Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

May be this bug already reported 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zeitgeist-extensions/+bug/757727